# How to continue to train a model with new classes and data?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I have trained a model successfully and now I want to continue training it with new data. If a given data with the same amount of classes it works fine. But having more data then initially it will give me the error:

> ValueError: Shapes (?, 14) and (?, 21) are not compatible

How can I dynamically increase the number of classes in my trained model or how to make the model accept a lesser number of classes? Do I need to save the classes in a pickle file?